# Show the price of in app purchase in Android

Tags: android

In my Android app I have a "shop" activity with a in-app section. I want show the price of my in app purchase at the time of the opening (not in the Google popup, after button pressing). I have searched in Google and I have tried this function, which I call in "onCreate", with argument "id.my.inapp". But if I test it on my device, the app stop itself.

I think maybe something of argument or parameters is wrong, or I have wrongly edited the suggested code (I have only edited the part with in app name).

```js
public String getPricesInapp(String packageName) throws RemoteException, JSONException{


        ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
        skuList.add("id.my.inapp");
        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

        Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,packageName, "inapp", querySkus);


        int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        if (response == 0) {
            ArrayList<String> responseList
                    = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

            for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                String sku = object.getString("productId");
                String price = object.getString("price");

                if(sku.contains("id.my.inapp")) return price;

            }
        }
        return "Not found";


    }
```

Comment: Can you post your exception data?

Comment: Sorry, but I have tested only on physical device (in the emulator the in app system doesn't work, normally) and on my device I haven't the gradle output console... Thank for your answer!